# How to use pycurl when url contain non-English language?

Tags: python, pycurl

This is the example on the pycurl's sourceforge page. And if the url contain like Chinese. What process should we do? Since pycurl does not support unicode?

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://www.python.org/")
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Accept:"])

import StringIO
b = StringIO.StringIO()
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
c.perform()
print b.getvalue()
```

Comment: I never used pycurl, but it seems unmaintained. I would recommend you to try a more modern library, like requests, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/.

Comment: Pycurl is well maintained. I would recommend against requests, since requests is not thread-safe and has a memory-leak issue. @Oz123

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that demonstrates three separate issues:

- non-ascii characters in Python source code
- non-ascii characters in the url
- non-ascii characters in the html content

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
from StringIO import StringIO
import pycurl

title = u"UNIX时间" # 1
url = "https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + urllib.quote(title.encode('utf-8')) # 2

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Accept:"])

b = StringIO()
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
c.perform()

data = b.getvalue() # bytes
print len(data), repr(data[:200])

html_page_charset = "utf-8" # 3
html_text = data.decode(html_page_charset)
print html_text[:200] # 4
```

Note: all `utf-8` in the code are compeletely independent from each other.

1. Unicode literals use whatever character encoding you defined at the
   top of the file. Make sure your text editor respects that setting
2. Path in the url should be encoded using `utf-8` before it is
   percent-encoded (urlencoded)
3. There are several ways to find out a html page charset. See
   [Character encodings in HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML). Some libraries such as [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) mentioned by @Oz123 do it automatically:

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   import requests

   r = requests.get(u"https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX时间")
   print len(r.content), repr(r.content[:200]) # bytes
   print r.encoding
   print r.text[:200] # Unicode
   ```
4. [To print Unicode to console](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails) you could use [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) to set character encoding that your terminal understands

See also [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/Unicode.html) and Python-specific [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try urllib.quote, which will replace non-ASCII characters by an escape sequence:

```
import urllib

url_to_fetch = urllib.quote(unicode_url)
```

edit: only the path should be quoted, you will have to split the complete URL with urlparse, quote the path, and then use urlunparse to obtain the final URL to fetch.

Comment: I assume the OP means "the page content" is non-ascii, not url string itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just encode your url in "utf-8", and everything would be fine. from the docs:

> Under Python 3, the bytes type holds arbitrary encoded byte strings. PycURL will accept bytes values for all options where libcurl specifies a “string” argument:

```
>>> import pycurl
>>> c = pycurl.Curl()
>>> c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, b'Foo\xa9')
# ok
```

> The str type holds Unicode data. PycURL will accept str values containing ASCII code points only:

```
>>> c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Foo')
# ok

>>> c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Foo\xa9')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa9' in position 3: 
ordinal not in range(128)

>>> c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Foo\xa9'.encode('iso-8859-1'))
# ok
```

[1] http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/unicode.html